# Setting cassandra retry Policy option in spring-data 2

Tags: cassandra, spring-data, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

Setting the retry policy for Cassandra with spring Data 2 is deprecated.

Example Spring 1.5
    spring.data.cassandra.retry-policy=com.datastax.driver.core.policies.FallthroughRetryPolicy

How can I set the  retry policy in application properties with spring data 2

Answer (score 0):

here is a working example using a CassandraConfig class:

```java
    @Configuration
    public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.keyspacename}")
    private String keyspaceName;
    
    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.contactpoints}")
    private String contactPoints;
    
    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return keyspaceName;
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Override
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {

        CassandraClusterFactoryBean bean = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
        bean.setContactPoints(getContactPoints());
        bean.setKeyspaceCreations(getKeyspaceCreations());
        bean.setStartupScripts(getStartupScripts());
        bean.setJmxReportingEnabled(getMetricsEnabled());
        bean.setRetryPolicy(FallthroughRetryPolicy.INSTANCE);
        return bean;
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Override
    public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() {

        CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();

        session.setCluster(cluster().getObject());
        session.setConverter(cassandraConverter());
        session.setKeyspaceName(getKeyspaceName());
        session.setSchemaAction(getSchemaAction());
        session.setStartupScripts(getStartupScripts());
        session.setShutdownScripts(getShutdownScripts());

        return session;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected String getContactPoints() {
        return contactPoints;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected List<CreateKeyspaceSpecification> getKeyspaceCreations() {
        final CreateKeyspaceSpecification myKeyspaceSpecification = CreateKeyspaceSpecification.createKeyspace(keyspaceName)
                .ifNotExists()
                .with(KeyspaceOption.DURABLE_WRITES, true)
                .withSimpleReplication();
        return Arrays.asList(myKeyspaceSpecification);
    }
    
    @Override
    public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
        return SchemaAction.CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String[] getEntityBasePackages() {
        return new String[] { "com.example.model"};
    }
    
    @Override
    protected boolean getMetricsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }
}
```